# define a static array in class templates

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, static, definition

I have a static array inside a class template. The linker complains about a undefined symbol and even after applying the tips I saw on the web, I can't figure out what goes wrong.

**Header**

```cpp
template<unsigned int N1, unsigned int N2>
class Foo 
{
private:
    static const int Size = N1 * N2;

public:
// stuff

private:
    static float mArray[Size];

}
```

**CPP**

```cpp
template <unsigned int N1, unsigned int N2>
float Foo<N1, N2>::mArray[size] = {0};
```

The linker complains about Foo<...>::mArray not being defined. I got it to compile (and link) when I move the definition to the header but I know that this is bad practice for statics. What is the best approach here?

Cheers

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I wouldn't be so sure about the duplicate - none of the answers there actually mentions static data members, and it's not immediately obvious the rule applies to them as well. Especially as normally you would get a linker erro from putting a static data member definition in a header file.

Comment: @Angew Well, `static` class members of a template class aren't anyhow special regarding the rules and solutions mentioned in the dupe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with nearly everything else template-y, the definition of the static data member of a class template needs to be accessible in all translation units using it—in other words, put it in the header file. The compiler+linker are required to make this work without multiple-definition errors.